# Does Node@6 support puppeteer api to generate PDF

Tags: node.js, pdf, asynchronous, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I have successfully generated PDF using puppeteer api with latest version of Node i.e Node@8.  Here is the latest code. But the requirement is to generate PDF using puppeteer api with Node@6.

```
`const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('http://www.google.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
  await page.pdf({path: 'hn8.pdf', width: '1600px' , height: '800px'});
  await browser.close();
})();
module.exports = app;`
```

This code has await() and async which was introduced in Node7. I have searched few blogs and it says that the same can be done in Node6 as well. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just convert async functions to classic promises:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

puppeteer.launch().then(browser => {
  browser.newPage().then(page => {
    page
      .goto('http://www.google.com', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' })
      .then(page.pdf({ path: 'hn8.pdf', width: '1600px', height: '800px' }))
      .then(() => {
        browser.close();
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Everettss . But this returns a empty pdf. Adding return solves my issue.

Comment: Where did you have to add `return`?

Comment: After each promise added a return. below example            puppeteer.launch()
 .then(b => { browser = b; 
  return browser.newPage();})
 .then(a => {page = a; return a.goto('http://www.google.com')})